# Not understanding elliptic curve scalar multiplication to produce Ethereum address

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis

This is the equation

```
Public key = Private key * G
```

Here,

```
 Private key = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

 G = (0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,
 0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8)
```

As Private key =1, there is no iteration on the curve. So value of  Public key should be G

But the reality is

```
Public key = 0x7E5F4552091A69125d5DfCb7b8C2659029395Bdf
```

NB: Well none Ethereum Private key and Public key

Is there anybody who could make me understand how?

Could you help me showing any math how

`Private key = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`
is converted into `0x7E5F4552091A69125d5DfCb7b8C2659029395Bdf` as wallet address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Yellow Paper of Ethereum](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf)

> For a given private key, $p_r$ , the Ethereum address $A(p_r )$ (a 160-bit value) to which it corresponds is defined as the right most 160-bits of the Keccak hash of the corresponding ECDSA public key:
> $$ A(p_r ) = B_{96\ldots255}(\textit{KEC}(\textit{ECDSAPUBKEY}(p_r )$$

- first find the public key in the ECC using the private key $k$

  $$PublicKey = k \cdot G=  [k]G  $$ set $k=1$ and get $PublicKey = G$
- Now, we need to use Keccak-256 with $x$ and $y$ coordinate is concatanated, we can use an [online](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) tool, **Never Use for real keys online**
- we get

  ```
  c0a6c424ac7157ae408398df7e5f4552091a69125d5dfcb7b8c2659029395bdf
  ```
- Take the rightmost 160-bit from the result or 40-hex from already hex encoded result of hashing.

  ```
  0x7E5F4552091A69125D5DFCB7B8C2659029395BDF
  ```
- Now, we have arrived at your Ethereum address.

Comment: Thank you very much